# Excel Conditional Formatting - Indirect Address Formula

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, excel-indirect

There are several other threads that seem to have addressed similar questions, but I am still unable to find a solution that works for me...  I am using Excel 2016, and when I try to create a conditional formatting rule that uses `AND()`, `INDIRECT()`, and `ADDRESS()` functions the rule does not seem to work.

My rule applies to `=$J:$BZ`, and is the following:

`=AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ABS(ROW()-3),COLUMN(),4))>0,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),9,3))="Example String")`

I am simply trying to reference the value of a cell three rows above the current row (with the `ABS()` section simply to mitigate any errors if the row number becomes less than 1 for the first three rows) as well as the value of the fixed column (column "I" or 9).

This should be using `A1` style, but I have also tried `R1C1` style with no success... pulling this formula out of conditional formatting and entering it into the desired cell results in `TRUE`.

Comment: In this particular case you can sidestep the use of row() and indirect() by using the fact that CF formulas wrap around from the end of the spreadsheet and use =AND(J108574>0,$I1="Example String")

Comment: @TomSharpe thank you for the response!  I didn't realize that conditional formatting wraps throughout the entire spreadsheet, so this was a much cleaner way to resolve my issue.